# PHP: how to create associative array by key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have simple array

```
array( 
   array( 'id'=>5, 'something' => 2, 'dsadsa' => 'fsfsd )
   array( 'id'=>20, 'something' => 2, 'dsadsa' => 'fsfsd )
   array( 'id'=>30, 'something' => 2, 'dsadsa' => 'fsfsd )
)
```

How to create associative array by id field (or something else) from it in the right way?

```
array( 
   '5' => array(  'something' => 2, 'dsadsa' => 'fsfsd )
   '20' => array(  'something' => 2, 'dsadsa' => 'fsfsd )
   '30' => array(  'something' => 2, 'dsadsa' => 'fsfsd )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NikitaKuhta, nope.  There is no slice function which returns a column of values in a 2D keyed table associated with a given key or column heading.  You can use some of the callback array_... functions, but you will still need to execute a custom function per element so its just not worth it.  I don't like Core Xii's solution as this corrupts the original array as a side effect.  I suggest that you *don't* use references here:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($original_array as $slice) {
    $id = (string) $slice['id'];
    unset($slice['id']);
    $new_array[$id] = $slice;
}
# And now you don't need the missing unset( $slice)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines.

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($original_array as &$slice)
    {
    $id = (string) $slice['id'];
    unset($slice['id']);
    $new_array[$id] = $slice;
    }
```

Comment: I can do it with foreach, but I thought, that PHP have some specials functions for that task...

Comment: It's a pretty specific task, I don't think there's a built-in function for it.

Comment: This has a side effect of deleting the ['id'] elts from the original array, and because you don't unset $slice, any assignments to it will generate more side-effects in $new_array!